# Pythonically incrementing numbers in an arbitrary slice of a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This fragment of code shows the DataFrame I'd like to create

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='4/1/2012', periods=10))
df['foo'] = 7
df['what_i_want'] = [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0]
```

The result looks like:

```
    foo what_i_want
2012-04-01  7   0
2012-04-02  7   0
2012-04-03  7   0
2012-04-04  7   0
2012-04-05  7   1
2012-04-06  7   2
2012-04-07  7   3
2012-04-08  7   0
2012-04-09  7   0
2012-04-10  7   0
```

I am trying to figure out a way that i can create these `1,2,...,n` series on arbitrary slices of a series.  IE: `df['2012-04-05':'2012-04-07'] = magic_function()`

But I'm not sure how to do this without using loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can slice with `loc` and assign a `range`.

```
df['what_i_want'] = 0
df.loc['2012-04-05':'2012-04-07', 'what_i_want'] = range(1, 4)

df

            foo  what_i_want
2012-04-01    7            0
2012-04-02    7            0
2012-04-03    7            0
2012-04-04    7            0
2012-04-05    7            1
2012-04-06    7            2
2012-04-07    7            3
2012-04-08    7            0
2012-04-09    7            0
2012-04-10    7            0
```

Answer (score 2):

First extract indices for new `Series` with `range` by `length` of slice:

```
idx = df.loc['2012-04-05':'2012-04-07'].index
df['new'] = pd.Series(range(1, len(idx)+1), index=idx).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
```

Or assign `range`, but then is necessary replace `NaN`s and convert to `int`:

```
l = len(df.loc['2012-04-05':'2012-04-07'].index)
df.loc['2012-04-05':'2012-04-07', 'new'] = range(1, l+1)
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
            foo  new
2012-04-01    7    0
2012-04-02    7    0
2012-04-03    7    0
2012-04-04    7    0
2012-04-05    7    1
2012-04-06    7    2
2012-04-07    7    3
2012-04-08    7    0
2012-04-09    7    0
2012-04-10    7    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df.loc['2012-04-08':'2012-04-10']['what_i_want']= \
df.loc['2012-04-08':'2012-04-10'].apply(lambda x:1, axis=1).cumsum()
```

using a cumulative sum for the selected values after converting them to 1s.